# Problems creating a Java Bean inheritance structure

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, javabeans

I am trying to create create what I think is a simple inheritance structure with Java Beans (I have never worked with them before).  I was given code which has a base class defined as

```
public class CreateDialogFactory {
    priavte static beanId;

    protected CreateDialogFactory() { }
    protected CreateDialogFactory(String beanId) { this.beanId = beanId; }

    public static CreateScenarioDialog getInstace() {
        return SpringHelper.getInstance(beanId, CreateScenarioDialogFactory.class);

    }
}
```

Inheriting from this class is two classes which are defined:

```
@Component(ACreateScenarioDialogFactory.BEAN_ID)
public class ACreateScenarioDialogFactory extends CreateDialogFactory {

    private static String BEAN_ID = "create-a-scenario";

    protected ACreateScenarioDialogFactory() {
        super(BEAN_ID);
    }
}
```

AND

```
@Component(BCreateScenarioDialogFactory.BEAN_ID)
public class BCreateScenarioDialogFactory extends CreateDialogFactory {

    private static String BEAN_ID = "create-b-scenario";

    protected BCreateScenarioDialogFactory() {
        super(BEAN_ID);
    }
}
```

my xml spec is very simple -

My problem is, when I compile I get `No unique bean of type [a.b.CreateDialogFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [create-a-scenario, create-b-scenario]`

Even when I comment out the bean definitions in the xml spec.

Comment: Your project structure would help, along with how you have declared interfaces, and are they correctly implemented. Spring requires interfaces for IOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inversion of control in Spring is intended to be used with interfaces. In your code, base class of hierachy is taken as type when generating the beans so `SpringHelper.getInstance(beanId, CreateScenarioDialogFactory.class)` can't choose between `ACreateScenarioDialogFactory` or `BCreateScenarioDialogFactory` because they are the same type.

Comment: Ultimately my concern is with the `getInstance` method.  Other methods are calling `CreateDialogFactory.getInstance()` and it used to return just a  `ACreateScenarioDialogFactory` now I need it to return one or the other.  How would I do that?